# When i run react-native ios on device, i got an Error in tests

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, build

I run `react-native run-ios` i got this error!

```
** BUILD FAILED **


    The following commands produced analyzer issues:

    Analyze /Users/carlito/Desktop/bumeapp/node_modules/react- 
    native/React/Base/RCTModuleMethod.mm normal x86_64
    Analyze /Users/carlito/Desktop/bumeapp/node_modules/react- 
    native/Libraries/Network/RCTNetInfo.m normal x86_64
    (2 commands with analyzer issues)

The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/carlito/Desktop/bumeapp/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Bume.io.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Bume.ioTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Bume.ioTests.o /Users/carlito/Desktop/bumeapp/ios/Bume.ioTests/Bume.ioTests.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Bume.io.app
Launching io.bume.app
io.bume.app: ΩΩΩΩ
```

This build installs the app on the device, but does not work. I tried doing it by Xcode but it has 2 errors in the following file:

Bume.ioTests.m

[ERROR 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23NHZ.png)

If it is necessary I edit this post with the code that they want, because I do not really know anything of why this error is happening. I made a few attempts by running the `react-native upgrade`, solved most of the other errors I had, but still have 2.

I don't know what is wrong with my main.jsbundle, it means to be an error but i dont't know if this file is my main.m in my ios folder in react project and what is wrong too.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

I just run the following commands:
`react-native upgrade`. Then, delete your `ios` and `android` folders. Then, run `react-native eject`. Then, run `react-native link`.

Finally, run the `react-native run-ios` command again.

I think the problem was, my folders were old and I updated them with the new version of React